# How to generate a binary blob object in java of a specific size?

Tags: java, encoding, arrays, blob, bytebuffer

I am trying to build an opaque Binary Blob 64-bit encoded with any garbage/random content, also trying to make it in such a way so that I can specify the size in Kb for the blob of data to generate into it.

The purpose of it is to bench-mark the write throughput of a DB application which support the blob datatype (e.g. C*). The blob does not need to be unique, hence it can be constructed once and just reuse it to avoid latency client side due to GC and object creation.

I have naively tried using a `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bSize)` thinking I could just use whatever garbage it will pickup from memory, however I am doubtful that this approach works.

Any suggestions as to how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Linux, this little command line trick creates dummy files quickly:

```
 dd if=/dev/zero of=FileName bs=1024 count=1000
```

`count * bs` = filesize

Then:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO table (blob) VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
File blob = new File("path_to_FileName");
FileInputStream   fis = new FileInputStream(blob);
stmt.setBinaryStream(1, fis, (int) blob.length());
stmt.execute();
```

Comment: That's weird to make a solution for tests(!) in Java(!) be platform dependent.

Comment: "The blob does not need to be unique, hence it can be constructed once and just reuse it to avoid latency client side due to GC and object creation." So make one system call to create the blob, and then do all of the testing in Java with an already created file. Not weird at all

Comment: Ok, replacing GC latency with IO latency, not great either.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the data to be random you can use Random.nextBytes(byte[]);  however it is rare for such systems to care about the contents so you can just use all zeros.

```
byte[] blob = new byte[byteCount];

// optionally
// new Random().nextBytes(blob);

stmt.setBinaryStream(1, new ByteArrayInputStream(blob), blob.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom implementation of InputStream to produce random data:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomInputStream extends InputStream
{
    private int available;
    private Random random = new Random();

    public RandomInputStream(final int totalSize)
    {
        this.available = totalSize;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException
    {
        if(available == 0)
            return -1;
        --available;
        return random.nextInt(256);
    }


    @Override
    public int available() throws IOException
    {
        return available;
    }
}
```

And then just use it as usual:

```
InputStream is = new RandomInputStream(1024*1024);
stmt.setBinaryStream(1, is, is.available());
```

This would be the fastest solution possible.

Answer (score 0):

byte[] blob = new byte[byteCount];

// optionally
// new Random().nextBytes(blob);

stmt.setBinaryStream(1, new ByteArrayInputStream(blob), blob.length);